# c# RestAPIでのバージョン管理方法を教えてください。

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, asp.net

Visual Studio2013 C#でAPIを作成しています。
バージョン管理をしたいんですが、よくわかりませんので、
できればコードのサンプルと一緒にバージョン管理方法を教えていただきたいんです。
下書きのURLになれるようバージョン管理をしたいんです。
バージョン管理した時のURL : https://testapi.com/api/v1/history 
現在のURL : https://testapi.com/api/history

ソースコード

```
namespace TestAPI.WebApi.Controllers
{
   public class HistoryController : ApiControllerBase
   {
       [UseSSL]
       [Authorize]
       public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(HistoryRequestModels model)
       {
           ...
           return "test";

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLでバージョン指定する実装方法が複数紹介されています。
ASP.NET Web API でバージョニングを実現する方法を調べた
http://blog.shibayan.jp/entry/20150320/1426831063

[SDammann.WebApi.Versioning](https://github.com/Sebazzz/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning)というツールもあるそうです。